# Merge query using two tables in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am very new to SQL and SQL server, would appreciate any help with the following problem.

I am trying to update a share price table with new prices.

The table has three columns: share code, date, price.

The share code + date = PK

As you can imagine, if you have thousands of share codes and 10 years' data for each, the table can get very big. So I have created a separate table called a share ID table, and use a share ID instead in the first table (I was reliably informed this would speed up the query, as searching by integer is faster than string).

So, to summarise, I have two tables as follows:

```
Table 1 = Share_code_ID (int), Date, Price
Table 2 = Share_code_ID (int), Share_name (string)
```

So let's say I want to update the table/s with today's price for share ZZZ. I need to:

1. Look for the Share_code_ID corresponding to 'ZZZ' in table 2
2. If it is found, update table 1 with the new price for that date, using the Share_code_ID I just found
3. If the Share_code_ID is not found, update both tables

Let's ignore for now how the Share_code_ID is generated for a new code, I'll worry about that later.

I'm trying to use a merge query loosely based on the following structure, but have no idea what I am doing:

```
MERGE INTO [Table 1]           
USING (VALUES (1,23-May-2013,1000)) AS SOURCE (Share_code_ID,Date,Price)                    

{ SEEMS LIKE THERE SHOULD BE AN INNER JOIN HERE OR SOMETHING }   

ON  Table 2 = 'ZZZ' 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Table 1.Price = 1000    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT { TO BOTH TABLES }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html
You don't give no sample data, no error text, no even question. Here is nothing to talk about.

Comment: 1) try doing it as stored procedure, and you would have to pass it Share_name, Date and Price and 'ZZZ' for input.
2) don't name your tables and columns using spaces and little letters. You seems totally confused by separating identificators. And actually using standard "Table 1" or anti-standard [Table 1] is very annoying and dull.  `Table 2 = 'ZZZ'`  is non-sense!

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx

You use Table1 for `target table` and Table2 for `source table`
You want to do action, when given ID is not found in Table2 - in the `source table`

In the documentation, that you had read already, that corresponds to the clause

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE ...  THEN <merge_matched>
```

and the latter corresponds to

```
<merge_matched>::=
    { UPDATE SET <set_clause> | DELETE }
```

Ergo, you cannot insert into source-table there.
You could use triggers for auto-insertion, when you insert something in Table1, but that will not be able to insert proper Shared_Name - trigger just won't know it.

So you have two options i guess.

1) make T-SQL code block - look for Stored Procedures. I think there also is a construct to execute anonymous code block in MS SQ, like EXECUTE BLOCK command in Firebird SQL Server, but i don't know it for sure.

2) create updatable SQL VIEW, joining Table1 and Table2 to show last most current date, so that when you insert a row in this view the view's on-insert trigger would actually insert rows to both tables. And when you would update the data in the view, the on-update trigger would modify the data.